# Installing I210 driver on a running kernel?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, driver, cross-compiling

I am working on a basic kernel which is not supporting Make command.
The drivers provided by intel use Makefile to install.
So I cant copy the file into my target and run make.

I tried to cross compile but its giving following error.

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:92: 
stack protector enabled but no compiler support
rm: cannot remove`/home/sigma/karthik1/igb-5.3.4.4/src/.tmp_versions/igb.mod': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [crmodverdir] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2

Comment: Your user has no permission to remove kernel module `igb.mod`. So try to use `sudo` to make the driver, or change file permission.

Comment: I am trying to create so that use that in my target .But when I try to do rpmbuild(In cross Compiler mode) I am getting following error.                                                                                           arm-none-eabi-ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386
Supported emulations: armelf

Comment: Smell like you are trying to use non cross compiled libs or you are using wrong cross compiler.

Comment: How can I install Make in my target linux?

Comment: Even apt-get commands are not available.

Comment: See also now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566045/how-to-install-make-utility-in-a-basic-linux-kernel but if you are unable to read even simple error messages, what chances do you have of understanding an answer to one of these questions?